App crashing in only release mode when invoking onLongPress event - Android/iOS
I added support for Android 14 to my app, but after that, the app crashed when invoking the onLongPress event with TouchableOpacity in release mode. The app is not crashing in debug mode.
On digging the crash with the logcat, the app was crashing with the error: Invalid Hook Call

You might have mismatched versions of React and React DOM.
You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks.
You might have more than one copy of React in the same app.

I tried everything but no luck the error is still on it, please help
Stack Trace:
12-09 13:33:32.684 22511 22571 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: mqt_native_modules
12-09 13:33:32.684 22511 22571 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.autoscan.appv9, PID: 22511
12-09 13:33:32.684 22511 22571 E AndroidRuntime: com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException: Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
12-09 13:33:32.684 22511 22571 E AndroidRuntime: 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
12-09 13:33:32.684 22511 22571 E AndroidRuntime: 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
12-09 13:33:32.684 22511 22571 E AndroidRuntime: 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
12-09 13:33:32.684 22511 22571 E AndroidRuntime: See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem., stack:
12-09 13:33:32.684 22511 22571 E AndroidRuntime: Ur@91:41069
12-09 13:33:32.684 22511 22571 E AndroidRuntime: <unknown>@424:1218
12-09 13:33:32.684 22511 22571 E AndroidRuntime: onLongPress@915:3684
12-09 13:33:32.684 22511 22571 E AndroidRuntime: value@212:7309
12-09 13:33:32.684 22511 22571 E AndroidRuntime: value@212:6947
12-09 13:33:32.684 22511 22571 E AndroidRuntime: value@212:9161
12-09 13:33:32.684 22511 22571 E AndroidRuntime: <unknown>@212:5059
12-09 13:33:32.684 22511 22571 E AndroidRuntime: k@117:535
12-09 13:33:32.684 22511 22571 E AndroidRuntime: callTimers@117:2632
12-09 13:33:32.684 22511 22571 E AndroidRuntime: value@42:3492
12-09 13:33:32.684 22511 22571 E AndroidRuntime: <unknown>@42:747
12-09 13:33:32.684 22511 22571 E AndroidRuntime: value@42:2538
12-09 13:33:32.684 22511 22571 E AndroidRuntime: value@42:719
12-09 13:33:32.684 22511 22571 E AndroidRuntime: value@-1
12-09 13:33:32.684 22511 22571 E AndroidRuntime: 
12-09 13:33:32.684 22511 22571 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ExceptionsManagerModule.reportException(ExceptionsManagerModule.java:83)
12-09 13:33:32.684 22511 22571 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
12-09 13:33:32.684 22511 22571 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(JavaMethodWrapper.java:372)
12-09 13:33:32.684 22511 22571 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(JavaModuleWrapper.java:151)
12-09 13:33:32.684 22511 22571 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
12-09 13:33:32.684 22511 22571 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:958)
12-09 13:33:32.684 22511 22571 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-09 13:33:32.684 22511 22571 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:27)
12-09 13:33:32.684 22511 22571 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:230)
12-09 13:33:32.684 22511 22571 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:319)
12-09 13:33:32.684 22511 22571 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:226)
12-09 13:33:32.684 22511 22571 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
12-09 13:33:32.713  2389 23067 W ActivityManager: crash : com.autoscan.appv9,10331
12-09 13:33:32.715  2389  3097 W ActivityTaskManager:   Force finishing activity com.autoscan.appv9/.MainActivity

Package.json
{
  "name": "ApexScan",
  "version": "0.1.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider react-native start",
    "start-cache": "react-native start --reset-cache",
    "pod": "cd ios && pod install && cd ..",
    "adb": "adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081",
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "startiPhone11": "npx react-native run-ios --udid 502CA678-5086-448F-B62B-8F56473E903E",
    "startiPad11": "npx react-native run-ios --udid AB365004-86C5-4B5D-84DB-17EE5A4412BB",
    "startiPhoneSE": "npx react-native run-ios --udid 7457F48E-DCE8-43C7-895C-C475B8AA7A84",
    "ios-xed": "xed -b ios",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx",
    "createCleanReleaseAPK": "cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease && cd .. && open ./android/app/build/outputs/apk/release",
    "createCleanBundle": "cd android && ./gradlew clean && ./gradlew bundleRelease && cd .. && open ./android/app/build/outputs/bundle/release"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.15.5",
    "@react-native-community/checkbox": "^0.5.8",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^12.9.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^13.1.0",
    "@react-native-google-signin/google-signin": "^7.0.1",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "5.11.11",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.4",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "6.1.0",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "5.14.5",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "1.6.1",
    "@stripe/stripe-react-native": "^0.35.1",
    "@types/styled-components": "5.1.11",
    "@types/styled-components-react-native": "5.1.1",
    "axios": "0.21.1",
    "fast-xml-parser": "^3.20.3",
    "geolib": "^3.3.1",
    "lodash": "4.17.21",
    "lottie-ios": "^3.2.3",
    "lottie-react-native": "^4.1.3",
    "moment": "2.29.1",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-native": "0.66.0",
    "react-native-barcode-mask": "^1.2.4",
    "react-native-camera": "^4.2.1",
    "react-native-currency-input": "^1.0.1",
    "react-native-date-picker": "4.2.0",
    "react-native-dropdown-picker": "5.1.23",
    "react-native-error-boundary": "1.1.11",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "1.10.3",
    "react-native-html-to-pdf": "^0.12.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "0.9.4",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "2.5.6",
    "react-native-logs": "^5.0.1",
    "react-native-modal": "12.0.3",
    "react-native-onesignal": "^4.5.3",
    "react-native-print": "^0.11.0",
    "react-native-rename": "^2.9.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.4.0",
    "react-native-share": "^7.2.0",
    "react-native-size-matters": "^0.4.2",
    "react-native-smtp-mailer": "^1.2.5",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "3.2.0",
    "react-native-svg": "12.1.1",
    "react-native-svg-transformer": "0.14.3",
    "react-native-toast-message": "^1.4.9",
    "react-redux": "7.2.4",
    "redux": "4.1.0",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "2.13.9",
    "redux-logger": "3.0.6",
    "redux-persist": "6.0.0",
    "redux-saga": "1.1.3",
    "rn-fetch-blob": "^0.12.0",
    "styled-components": "5.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.12.9",
    "@babel/runtime": "7.12.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "2.0.0",
    "@types/jest": "26.0.23",
    "@types/lodash": "4.14.172",
    "@types/react-native": "0.64.5",
    "@types/react-native-html-to-pdf": "^0.8.1",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.18",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "16.9.2",
    "@types/redux-logger": "3.0.9",
    "babel-jest": "26.6.3",
    "eslint": "7.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^5.1.0",
    "jest": "26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.64.0",
    "react-native-codegen": "0.0.7",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.1",
    "typescript": "^3.8.3"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "@types/react": "17"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "ts",
      "tsx",
      "js",
      "jsx",
      "json",
      "node"
    ]
  }
}



Code Fragment
const renderItem: ListRenderItem<TSticker> = ({ item }) => {
    return (
      <>
        <ItemContainer
          style={{
            backgroundColor: selectedStickers.some(
              (items: any) => items._id == item._id,
            )
              ? COLORS.gray
              : COLORS.darkBottomBar,
          }}
          activeOpacity={0.8}
          onPress={() => handlePress(item)}
          onLongPress={() => {
            handlerMultiSelection(item)
            setSelectedStickerId(item._id)
          }}>
          <View style={{ marginLeft: 10 }}>
            {!!(item.type === 'used') ? (
              <Assets.CAR_GREEN_ICON />
            ) : (
              <Assets.CAR_ICON />
            )}
          </View>

          <InfoWrapper>
            <TextWrapper>
              <ModelText
                style={{
                  color: selectedStickers.some(
                    (items: any) => items._id == item._id,
                  )
                    ? COLORS.white
                    : COLORS.gray,
                }}>
                {item.model}
              </ModelText>

              <Divider width={10} />

              <MarkText>{item.make}</MarkText>
            </TextWrapper>

            <Divider height={6} />

            <BottomTextWrapper>
              <VinText>{item.vinCode}</VinText>
              <Date style={styles.date}>
                {moment(item.createdAt).format('MM.DD.YYYY')}
              </Date>
              <Date>{moment(item.createdAt).format('LT')}</Date>
            </BottomTextWrapper>
          </InfoWrapper>
          <Assets.ARROW_ICON
            style={{
              transform: [{ rotate: '180deg' }],
            }}
          />
        </ItemContainer>

        <Divider height={6} />
      </>
    )
  }

 const handlerMultiSelection = (sticker: TSticker) => {
    if (selectedStickers.some((items: any) => items._id === sticker._id)) {
      let filteredArray = null
      filteredArray = selectedStickers.filter(
        (items: any) => items._id !== sticker._id,
      )
      setSelectedStickers(filteredArray)
    } else {
      let stickersArr = []
      stickersArr.push(...selectedStickers, sticker)
      setSelectedStickers(stickersArr)
    }
  }


Maybe a minify bug?

I manually created the release APK, still crashes.

Post the actual stack trace.  We're not going to guess with less than half the info.

@GabeSechan I just posted the actual stack trace, please look into it.

Can you please share the code fragment related to the issue?

@ilyabreev added the code fragment, the issue is coming at onLongPress in release, however, it's perfectly working on the debug APK.

@WahasAliMughal It is hard to tell what's the problem with your component without full code listing related to the issue. By the way such errors won't crash your app in debug mode so it's not strange - this is by design. Do you have red error box with same error while developing your app?

@ilyabreev While developing the app I'm not getting any errors, the functionality is working as expected.

So after struggling for 5 days and banging my head on the table, I finally solved the issue by this Release APK Not Updating With JavaScript Code
It was related to cache, the build was created from the old code and wasn't taking effect of the latest changes.
